# how to add proxy authentication details to webclient object

Tags: c#, proxy, webclient

I have some code that's throwing a 407 unauthorized exception.

I am trying to download a file and below is my example code. I've tried with netcredentials and webproxy but in vain.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
NetworkCredential netCred=new NetworkCredential();
netCred.UserName="<<userid>>";
netCred.Password="<<password>>";
netCred.Domain="<<windowsdomainname>>";
webClient.Credentials = netCred;
WebProxy wp = new WebProxy();
wp.Credentials = netCred;
wp.Address = new Uri(@"http://proxy-xx.xxxx.co.uk:8080/proxy.pac");
webClient.Proxy = wp;
webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.win-rar.com/postdownload.html?&L=0", @"c:\winrar.exe");
```

Comment: why are you using proxy instead of direct download.

Comment: @Furqan many thanks for your response. I tried just with NetworkCredentials but couldn't hence added WebProxy. This is a desktop application. Because I am using a corporate network, it will ask me for proxy authentication. I want to avoid that. Hence want to add credentials to my webclient object.

Comment: ok then remove the line `webClient.Credentials = netCred;` and try again.

Comment: Thanks again! Unfortunately the same error still. 407 -authentication required.

Comment: Are you sure your proxy is requiring authentication and the web server where file is present is not asking this.

Comment: I believe so as I am just trying to download a file from win-rar trial which doesn't require any form of authentication. I tried manually and I was able to download after entering my corporte internet proxy credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting 407 before finding your question.  Modified your source to the following, which works for me:

```
try
{
    var netCred = new NetworkCredential { UserName = "ununun", Password = @"pwpwpw", Domain = @"domain" };
    var webProxy = new WebProxy { Credentials = netCred };
    var webClient = new WebClient { Proxy = webProxy };
    webClient.DownloadFile(url, saveFileName);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception:\n{0}\n{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do yesterday.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
ICredentials cred;
cred = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
client.Proxy = new WebProxy("xxxx-proxy", true, null, cred);
```

Hope it help !